# How to read property file value in android xml file

Tags: android, xml

I want to know how to read property file value in android xml file for example:

android code :

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/teamname1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:text="@string/Team1"
android:textSize="6pt"/>
```

instead of hard-coding  `android:textSize = "6pt"` i want to configure it in another xml/property file like `key = value` as `size1 = 6pt` and then i can read like  `android:textSize = "../size1"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use `dimen.xml` file in values folder no need to hardcode

you need to use `dp` instead of `pt`

```
<resources>

    <!-- Default screen margins, per the Android Design guidelines. -->
    <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">16dp</dimen>

    <integer name="grid_num_rows">4</integer>
    <integer name="grid_num_cols">3</integer>

    <dimen name="text_size_teamname">6sp</dimen>
</resources>
```

when you use `dp` or `sp`  it will auto scale according to your device density

like 
if you use 6dp it will be change

```
for MDPI = 6px
for HDPI = 9px
for XHDPI= 12px
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can declare a dimension in the resouces as indicated by Padma -

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="textSizeSmall">14sp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Later, you use it like

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/teamname1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="@string/Team1"
    android:textSize="@dimen/textSizeSmall" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Create values/dimens.xml file and declare size1 dimension

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="size1">6pt</dimen>
</resources>
```

Then use this property in your layout.

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/teamname1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/Team1"
            android:textSize="@dimen/size1"/>
```